# Why .htaccess username and password protection is not working, I have folder and subfolder that need to be locked with separate auth

Tags: .htaccess

I need to password protect "folder1". That folder has a child folder "folder2" that needs to be locked with its own authentication.

I am using kali linux distro on VM.

I created .htaccess files in both folders pointing to their separate .htpasswd files located at /usr/local/etc/ as passwords and passwords2.

The problem is folder1 protection works until I specify the folder2 protection.

After that, protection does not work on any.

This is folder1 .htacces code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/passwords
Require user user1
```

This is folder2 .htaccess code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/passwords2
Require valid-user
```

At apache2.conf i added

```
<Directory /var/www/html/folder1>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/folder1/folder2>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

Comment: I am not totally sure, but I think the `Require` directives might be accumulating here, so that inside your folder2 it now demands that not only a `valid-user` needs to login, but also that it still has to be `user1`. On an Apache < 2.4 that could probably be handled via the `Satisfy` directive, making that `Any` inside folder2; Apache 2.4 handles things a bit differently, but I am not sure if `RequireAny` can actually be used in that situation, where the actual `Require` directives are in different locations.

Comment: I guess the easiest solution might be to just go with `Require valid-user` in folder1 already - and then simply provide a passwords file, that contains _only_ the credentials for `user1` to begin with.